# Recursive query for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server table `OBJECTS`, some objects are derived from another object and it is potentially infinitely many levels deep. Another table contains `ATTRIBUTES` for objects but it list the attributes for the main(parent) object but not its derived objects. I am searching for a way to get all the objects with a specific attribute(that may or may not be derived)?

I think a Common Table Expression (recursive query) is the way to go but I cant understand how to use it.

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE OBJECTS    
(
     [ID] INT,
     [PARENTID] INT, 
     [ObjectName] VARCHAR(32)
);    

INSERT INTO OBJECTS ([ID], [PARENTID], [ObjectName])
VALUES
    (1, 0, 'Parent1'),
    (2, 1, 'Parent2'),
    (3, 1, 'Item1'),
    (4, 1, 'Item2'),
    (5, 2, 'Item3'),
    (6, 0, 'Item4'),
    (7, 0, 'Item5');

CREATE TABLE ATTRIBUTES
(
     [ID] INT, 
     [AttributeName] VARCHAR(1)
);    

INSERT INTO ATTRIBUTES ([ID], [AttributeName])
VALUES
    (1, 'A'),
    (1, 'B'),
    (2, 'C'),
    (2, 'D'),
    (3, 'F'),
    (6, 'C'),
    (7, 'A');
```

Example question: how to list all objects(both 'native' and derived from parent objects) with a Attribute of 'A'?

Desired output:

```
ID  OBJECTNAME
---------------
1   Parent1
2   Parent2
3   Item1
4   Item2
5   Item3
7   Item5
```

Comment: Desired output is nothing but `select ID, ObjectName From Objects`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        o.id,
        o.parentid
    FROM objects o
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        c.id,
        o.parentid
    FROM objects o
    JOIN cte c ON c.parentid = o.id
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.attributename,
    c.id,
    o.objectname
FROM cte c
JOIN attributes a ON (a.id = c.id OR a.id = c.parentid)
    AND a.attributename = 'A'
LEFT JOIN objects o ON o.id = c.id
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Comment: When running this as a SQLFiddle(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0edf7/1), this returns "Invalid object name '#objects'." ?